# Take a month by month cumulative by grouped column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I would like to show the cumulative value by month using this dataset:

**Data**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
ID      val Date
AA:1    1   4/1/2022
AA:1    2   4/3/2022
AA:2    3   5/1/2022
AA:3    5   6/5/2022
AA:4    5   1/1/2023"""), sep='\s+')
```

**Desired**

```
ID  val  Date   
AA  3   4/1/2022
AA  6   5/1/2022
AA  11  6/1/2022
AA  16  1/1/2023
```

**Doing**

```
# Convert 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Group by ID and month, and calculate the cumulative sum
df['Cumulative_Value'] = df.groupby([df['ID'], df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')])['val'].cumsum()
```

However, the cumulative value is not computing.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%m/%d/%Y').dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()

df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.split(':').str[0]

# group by ID and month, then get the sum value for each group, then the cumsum of the group sums
df.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')])['val'].sum().cumsum()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original code snippet will work if you make sure that the `ID` column does not contain `:number`. As it is, right now only the first two rows represent non-unique identifiers. Doing `groupby` will create a row for every unique identifier, and so the computed result is different from the desired one.

A simple fix is to change the last line to:

```py
df['Cumulative_Value'] = df.groupby([df['ID'].str[:2], df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')])['val'].cumsum()
```

Of course the above assumes that only the first two characters are sufficient to identify the records of interest. If that is not the case, then it's best to create a separate column with a cleaned identifier, e.g. using the answer by @Mark:

```py
# this line is from answer by @Mark https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691995/10693596
df['Clean_ID'] = df['ID'].str.split(':').str[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.assign(**{'ID': df['ID'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]+)'),
              'Date': pd.to_datetime(df['Date']),
              'month': lambda x: x['Date'].dt.month,
              'year': lambda x: x['Date'].dt.year})
 .groupby(['ID', 'month', 'year'], sort=False)['val'].sum().cumsum()
 .reset_index()
 .assign(Date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(
     dict(year=x.pop('year'), month=x.pop('month'), day=1))))
```

Output:

```
   ID  val       Date
0  AA    3 2022-04-01
1  AA    6 2022-05-01
2  AA   11 2022-06-01
3  AA   16 2023-01-01
```